# How do I block receive requests on Azure Storage Queues

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I currently have a loop within which I poll an Azure Storage Queue as follows:

```
// Get the next messages
            var messages = await Queue.GetMessagesAsync(_messageBatchSize, lockTimeout, null, null);
```

I was expecting the await here would block for a configurable amount of time before  returning, but as it stands it returns immediately, which then prompts us to re-request a message immediately, and so we end up making a very large number of requests when the queue is not busy.

Can anyone tell me if there is a blocking await method available on the Azure Storage Queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath, Azure Storage queue API call for retrieving messages is just a simple REST GET. There is no blocking API call to be made, although you can specify a timeout for the call itself. You can look at the REST API details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-messages), where you can see only two time-based settings:

- Visibility timeout (how long you will get to work with a queue message before it resurfaces on the queue for other consumers)
- Call timeout (up to 30 seconds)

You'd need to implement your own type of backoff strategy, should the call return with zero messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought as much, we will wait for a period of time if no messages are returned.

Comment: If you switch to Service Bus queues there's a Message Pump that elegantly fakes a cloud "push" to your app (it's still polling under the hood, but nicer, as in single-malt vs. cheap club shot) - https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging/SendersReceiversWithQueues/Program.cs#L89

Comment: @evilSnobu - true. And lots of other features as well (pub/sub, ordering, at-most-once delivery, larger messages, rbac...), but losing a few things too (ability to modify invisibility lease, simplicity of setup &  interface, larger message store...).  I think the choosing between the two is a bit more complex and nuanced (like comparing single malts), which is why I was just focused on Azure queues here.